# How to pass ec2 variable from one ansible host to another

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to pass "private_dns_name" of my newly created ec2 instances to some other host in my ansible play book. I have tried using set_fact module to define the variable but no luck! This is ansible playbook entries for host1

```
- name: new EC2 instance
   hosts: host1   
  tasks:
    - name: Launch the new EC2 Instance
      ec2:
       aws_access_key: "{{ aws_id }}"
       aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_key }}"
       group_id: "{{ security_group_id }}"
       instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
       image: "{{ image }}"
       key_name: "{{ ssh_keyname }}"
       wait: yes
       wait_timeout: 900
       region: "{{ region }}"
       count: 1
       instance_tags:
         Name: Prod-Engineering
      register: ec2
    - name: Register public DNS fact
      set_fact: public_dns= "{{ item.private_dns_name }}"
      with_items: ec2.instances
```

After defining set_fact i am using below sample code to grab the private_dns_name to my other host2:

```
 - hosts: host2
   become: yes
   tasks:
    - command: ipa host-add "{{ public_dns}}" --password=xxxxx
```

but i am getting public_dns variable not defined error, when executing my playbook. How can i retrieve/pass variable from newly created ec2 instance to another other host/ec2 instance?

Answer (score 0):

Use ansible [magic variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts) to access other hosts' facts:

```
- hosts: host2
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - command: ipa host-add "{{ hostvars['host1']['public_dns'] }}" --password=xxxxx
```

Comment: Thanks Konstantin, but now i am getting "'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVars object' has no attribute" error in my playbook. i tried adding

Comment: Thanks Konstantin, but now i am getting "'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVars object' has no attribute" error. i tried adding   - debug: var=hostvars & - debug: msg= "{{ hostvars }}" under host1 but no luck either. What could be the issue here? thanks again!!

Comment: @DeepakPrasad first of all you can't use space after equal sign in this notation – use `debug: msg="{{ hostvars }}"`. With this space in `set_fact: public_ip= ...` public_ip will be always empty. But if you have `hostvars` undefined, something is totally wrong with your setup – it should be always available.

Comment: i am using ansible 2.1.1.0 and it doesn't really care about the space or no space after msg= either way it does not work and ends up with error: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVars object' has no attribute